# How to set up yaml file with gitlab to deploy when a specific file changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, gitlab, yaml, cicd

I'm trying to set up a YAML file for GitLab that will deploy to my QA server only when a specific folder has a change in it.

This is what I have but it doesn't want to work. The syntax doesn't register any errors.

```
deploy to qa:
  script: **aws scripts**
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - directory/*
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: qa
    url: **aws bucket url**
```

The problem seems to be with this section, the rest works without it. The documentation talks about using rules as a replacement for when only and changes are used together but I couldn't get that to work either.

```
only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - directory/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into is the `refs` section of your "only" rule. Per [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges) on "changes": "If you use refs other than branches, external_pull_requests, or merge_requests, changes can’t determine if a given file is new or old and always returns true." Since you're using `master` as your ref, you are running into this issue.

As you've ascertained, the correct answer to this is to use a `rules` keyword instead. The equivalent `rules` setup should be as follows:

```
deploy to qa:
  script: **aws scripts**
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - directory/*
      when: on_success
    - when: never
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: qa
    url: **aws bucket url**
```

Essentially, the rule is saying "If the commit you're building from exists on your default branch (`master` in your case), and you have changes in `directory/*`, then run this job when previous jobs have succeeded. ELSE, never run this job"

Note: Technically the `when: never` is implied if no clauses match, but I prefer including it because it explicitly states your expectation for the next person who has to read your CI/CD file.